# How "more" works?

Tags: pipe

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <my_helpers.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <time.h>




/*
 * Try to read from from stdin from both parent and child and see 
 * what happens
 */



int main()
{
    char buf[1024];
    int pipefd[2];
    int sts;
    char *childArgv[] = {"/usr/bin/more", NULL};

    if(pipe(pipefd) < 0)
    {
        perror("pipe()");
        exit(2);
    }


    if(fork() == 0)
    {
        if(dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO) < 0)
        {
            perror("dup()");
            exit(2);
        }
        close(pipefd[1]);
        execvp("/usr/bin/more", childArgv);


    }
    else
    {
        close(pipefd[0]);
        // in parent 
        while((sts = read(0, buf, 1024)) > 0)
        {
            buf[sts]='\0';
            write(pipefd[1], buf, sts);
        }
        wait();
    }
}
```

I have a simple program which spawns "more" which outputs the parent's writes. The "more" process's input is changed to pipe.

My doubt, is how does the "more" process interact with the user. It responds to "q", "space" commands etc. I am not sure how it happens as stdin is a not terminal.

More general form of my question is, when more reads input from pipe, how user interaction happens.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly, it will have (or create) a file handle to `/dev/tty` (or some other device file representing your terminal).

So, even if you redirect input from elsewhere, that can still be used to get information from the terminal itself.

In other words, while it will read the data to page from `stdin`, commands from the *user* will be pulled from this other file handle.

---

By way of example, the `less` program has a file called `ttyin.c`, with a function called `open_getchr()`, and it contains this little segment:

```
tty = open("/dev/tty", OPEN_READ);
```

The function is actually a fair bit more complex than that since it has to handle MS-DOS, Windows, OS/2 and various UNIX implementations, but that's basically what it boils down to for the latter.

---

For `more` specifically, it doesn't open a *new* file handle, rather it attempts to use the file descriptor of the `stderr` file handle for input as you can see from its `readch()` function:

```
int readch(void)
{
    unsigned char c;

    errno = 0;
    if (read(fileno(stderr), &c, 1) <= 0) {
        if (errno != EINTR)
            end_it(0);
        else
            c = otty.c_cc[VKILL];
    }
    return (c);
}
```

You can verify this with the command:

```
find / | more 2>/dev/null
```

which "breaks" more, exiting after the first page without prompting for your commands, because `stderr` no longer refers to your terminal device.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I though of this and  tried 'lsof'  on the corresponding terminal, but it doesn't not show "more". This means, more has some other trick or what is that i am missing ?

Comment: @Kumaran, needed some more research for that one but it turns out to be that `more` does a low-level `read()` on the file descriptor of `stderr`. That's why `lsof` isn't showing an extra file handle to `/dev/tty`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to answer the behavior. More seems to be reading from stderr.